# How do you exchange Authorization code for a OAuth2 token for google apis in android?

Tags: java, android, authorization, oauth-2.0

How do you exchange Authorization code for a OAuth2 token for google apis in android? If you go to https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/ you can exchange them, but I need to be able to do it in a android app! Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out myself! :)

All you need to do is make a HttpPost to accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token with the Authorization Code, client id, client secret, redirect_uri and grant type! I added the code to the answer so you can see how to do it exactly! Hope it helps

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", "<your_auth_code>"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "<your_client_id>"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "<your_client_secret>"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "<your_redirect_uri>"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code")); //Leave this line how it is   
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
Log.v("message", responseBody); // That just logs it into logCat
```

Comment: Additionally, you can use AccountManager with the 'oauth2:scope' tokenType to get a token for most services without having to authenticate manually (it uses Google accounts registered on the device).

Comment: lol I spent the longest time trying to get account manager to work, but it doesn't work with goo.gl yet, so that's why I had to use a webView.

Comment: Right, is sort of half-supported -- works with some services, but not with others.

Comment: This is really bad practice as it exposes the client secret in your Android code, leaving your application vulnerable to impersonation. Ideally you should use a server side web service on your own server where you can keep your client_secret secret!

Comment: FYI, in the oauth playground, the request now hits `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` instead of `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`.